# Not able to login to a website using requests python package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using the following script to login to https://www.mbaco.com/login. While I am not getting any error, I can't access the protected pages of the website. Plz help.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.mbaco.com/login'
payload = {
        '_username':"mysuername",
        '_password':"password"
        }
session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong url, the post is to `https://www.mbaco.com/login_check`, it is also a good  to add a user-agent:

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.mbaco.com/login_check'
payload = {
        '_username':"mysuername",
        '_password':"password"
        }
session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

If you want to see what gets posted and to where, open developer tools or firebug and you can see exactly what is happening, in this case you can see under the *other* tab exactly what is posted and to where:

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this but it still gives me response 200. When I tried posting the request via rest client, it did show 302. I can't figure out what is that I'm doing wrong.